# Faster way to run VBA for searching a range of dates out of the list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script which is used to search a range of specific dates out of a column with dates (from AparSheet), and find the dates which is earlier than the current next month and latter then the next month of the source date, that is stored in the source worksheet (WintelSheet), and copy the whole rows of data with dates in the range over the generated Sheet (copy from AparSheet to GeneratedSheet). The whole process takes around 40 plus minutes, which is very time-consuming and inefficient, though there are a lot data. At first, I'm trying to use filter, but my VBA script didn't work with the filter code. So I just simply use the if statement. I wonder how to modify the code to make it run faster, I already clear the data at the end of the script and off the screenupdating at the start of the script. Is there other ways to amend my script such as optimize the login within the code? (Another question using filtering function at [Filter by a range of months in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937980/filter-by-a-range-of-months-in-vba))

Files for testing: http://www.filedropper.com/samplefortesting

Here's my script:

```
Sub Paste_Dates()

    Dim WintelSheet As Worksheet, _
    GeneratedSheet As Worksheet, _
    AparSheet As Worksheet, _
    wkbSourceBook As Workbook, _
    wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook, _
    worksheetName As String, _
    Default As String
    Dim wSlastRow As Long
    Dim wSLastPasteRow As Long 'This will be used to check how far down has been copied thus far
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
    Dim NumberOfPasteRows As Long 'This will store how many months there are between dates, to paste into
    Dim PasteCounter As Integer
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtFinal As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    '// Set here Workbook(Sheets) names
    Set GeneratedSheet = wkbCrntWorkBook.Worksheets("APAR Hostname List")
    Set AparSheet = wkbCrntWorkBook.Worksheets("SG APAR")
    wSLastPasteRow = 2
    'extract data from another excel file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

        'Prompts user to choose which Worksheet they want to copy from
        MSG1 = MsgBox("Do you wish to copy from 'July CEP Server Patch Tracker' ?", vbYesNo, "Name of Worksheet")
        If MSG1 = vbYes Then
            worksheetName = "July CEP Server Patch Tracker"
        Else
            Default = "Sheet"
            worksheetName = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of Worksheet (Case-sensitive)", Default, Default)
        'End of first If statement
        End If

        Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        Set WintelSheet = wkbSourceBook.Sheets(worksheetName)

        With WintelSheet

        '//Find the last row of hostname in column A in WintelSheet
        wSlastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '//Find the last row of APAR No. in column J in AparSheet
        NumberOfPasteRows = AparSheet.Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '//Loop through each hostname in WintelSheet
            For X = 2 To wSlastRow
            '// W is the column with patch release date/PATCHED TILL
            If Not IsError(.Range("W" & X).Value) Then
                If IsDate(.Range("W" & X)) Then
                '//Calculate the last day of the month for dates in Column W (dtStart) and first day of the next current month (dtFinal)
                dtStart = DateSerial(Year(.Range("W" & X)), Month(.Range("W" & X)) + 1, 1)
                dtFinal = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, 1)
                'Loop though every rows from row 2 in AparSheet to copy rows with dates in range and put hostname in these rows
                For Y = 2 To NumberOfPasteRows
                With AparSheet
                'Find the dates which earlier then dtFinal latter than dtStart
                If .Range("L" & Y).Value >= DateValue(dtStart) And .Range("L" & Y).Value < DateValue(dtFinal) Then
                    'column A is the hostname list in WintelSheet
                        .Range("A" & Y).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=GeneratedSheet.Range("A" & wSLastPasteRow).EntireRow
                        WintelSheet.Range("A" & X).Copy Destination:=GeneratedSheet.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow)
                        wSLastPasteRow = wSLastPasteRow + 1

                End If
                End With
                Next Y
                End If
            End If
            Next X

        End With
        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
    End With

    'Free objects
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
    Set GeneratedSheet = Nothing
    Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing
    Set WintelSheet = Nothing
    Set AparSheet = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    '// Simple Msg Box
    MsgBox "Copy & Paste is Done."
End Sub
```

Here's a few screenshots for the sample data as requested.

WintelSheet:[image]

AparSheet: [image]

GeneratedSheet: [image]

Comment: please post a some screenshots too and explain a bit your code, just reverse engineer your code and understand it with so little background information is really tough.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have made some changes, please kindly review.

Comment: @user3964075 I need to sort date columns as many times as number of hostnames, usually will be at least 2 thousands of them. Thus it's impossible to do it manually. I have tried with filtering at here but it doesn't work[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937980/filter-by-a-range-of-months-in-vba]

Comment: @user3964075 Since I cannot change the original file, the best way to update A column will be either create another worksheet to update or use different parameter to record the row number?

Comment: @user3964075 Hi, you can just create some dates and hostnames according to the format in the screenshot, I'm not sure how to upload sample file.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions for the existing code:

1. move `With AparSheet` one line up, so it will run much rarely
2. `DateValue` conversion is an extra step and don't affects the output, delete them and just use: `.Range("L" & Y).Value >= dtStart And .Range("L" & Y).Value < dtFinal`
3. as you use "L" column of ApartSheet quite often, declare it: `set columnL =ApartSheet.Range("L1:L" & NumberOfPasteRows)`
4. probably less crucial in your code, but try to store results of calculations instead of calculating them several times

   - move `dtFinal = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, 1)` out from the loop
   - store `dtStart` in an array
5. if you have any calculation in any of the sheets, switch them off at the beginning of the macro, and switch on after it `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

However I also agree with the comments that big change can be achieved by changing logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, it's necessary to decrease number of cell reads (read columns to array), and maximise size of ranges copied at once.

To generate output list:

> - sort hosts sheet by date ascending
> - sort APAR sheet by date ascending
> - create output sheet
> - pass all three sheets to the following procedure

```
Sub CopyRows(shHosts  As Worksheet, shApar As Worksheet, shOutPut As Worksheet)
    Dim vApar As Variant, vHosts As Variant
    Dim iRows As Long, iOffset As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim dMaxDate As Date

    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    iRows = shApar.Range("J" & shApar.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    vApar = shApar.Range("L2:L" & iRows).Value2

    For i = 1 To iRows - 1
      vApar(i, 1) = vApar(i, 1) - Day(vApar(i, 1)) + 1
    Next

    iRows = shHosts.Range("W" & shHosts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    vHosts = shHosts.Range("W2:W" & iRows).Value2

    dMaxDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)
    j = 1
    iOffset = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vApar)
      If vApar(i, 1) >= dMaxDate Then Exit For
      While j < UBound(vHosts) And vHosts(j, 1) < vApar(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
      Wend

      If j > 1 Then
         shApar.Range(i+1 & ":" & i+1).Copy
         shOutPut.Range("2:2").Offset(iOffset, 0).Resize(j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         shOutPut.Range("b2:b2").Offset(iOffset, 0).Resize(j).Value2 = shHosts.Range("a2:a" & j+1).Value2
         iOffset = iOffset + j
      End If
    Next i

CleanUp:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In sample sheet 123 410 rows were generated in 0.9 second.

Comment: Hi I need to wait for your comment first to understand further the code

Comment: Hi can I confirm with you now the same hostname will be distrubuted separately with different apar number instead of being put together?

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to improve efficiency is to `Union` your ranges until you've hit a condition upon which you then act. I made this small change to a workbook that was deleting 23 of 24 rows for 24 hours worth of data for thousands of rows. Process would take a good 5 minutes if not longer; after the change...was done in an instant.